# How can I resolve cordova's "Plugin blocking main Thread for Xms" warning

Tags: cordova, threadpool

I am running my app on an android emulator through Eclipse.

When I try navigating to a new page, I see the warning "call to app.show blocked the main thread for xms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool" in the console log

I also got "call to file.requestallpaths blocked the main thread for xms..."

I checked the org.apache.cordova.file plugin and could see that file plugin was being called using the cordova thread pool.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: Here is the js scriplet:
//..................Privacy Policy....................//
$(document).on('change', '#accept', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#proceed').button('enable'); //enable input
  } else {
    $('#proceed').button('disable'); //disable input
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#proceed', function() {
  $.mobile.changePage('login.html', {
    reloadPage: true
  });
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit `eclipse.ini` for more high performance.

Change this line

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

into this

```
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
```

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seen the warning message since following your instruction. 
I cant up-vote your response due to my low reputation point.